# Angular : Wrapping ng-translate service inside custom pipe

Tags: angular

I am trying to create my own implementation of the TranslatePipe of ng-translate in my application . 
For that i built a pipe TranslateWrapperPipe which calls the TranslateService inside and returns the data .

```
export class TranslateWrapperPipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private translateService : TranslateService){
}

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
  if(value){
  console.log(value)
  return this.translateService.get(value)
  }
 }
}
```

But i am getting an Object back . 
If i do something like this `this.translateService.get(value).subscribe((res) => console.log(res))` i get the result but how to return it back to the original caller in the template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the custom pipe with the Async Pipe solved the issue . It seems like whenever an observable is returned from a pipe we need to add **async** pipe as well .

Comment: AsyncPipe provides unnecessary overhead. Actually, the pipe just should be impure and incorporate some ideas from AsyncPipe. It should be much simpler, because it's limited to one observable and string values.

Comment: Hi estus can you direct me to a better way to solve the problem ?

Comment: Yes, just make a subscription to observable like it's done inside of AsyncPipe. It's already simple enough, and custom pipe should be even simpler. I cannot write a class for you, but feel free to ask a new question if you will have specific problems with implementation.